# stuck in routes while setup of laravel 5.5 on shared host

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I followed a [tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) to setup Laravel 5.5 on a shared host (with no ssh access). The problem is routes aren't working and when visiting a page, the request is a kind of stuck. Browser tries to load the page continuously but it cannot and doesn't display any errors or exceptions.

Comment: make sure error log are active and environment is set to debug, maybe you'll catch the error

Comment: How were you able to run the commands mentioned in the tutorial without SSH?

Comment: @zuif Don't think those are obligatory to get things running. In fact, I found the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't getting any errors or anything, I didn't have any clue to solve this. I tried running a test by creating a route with a closure for response which does not require any database activity inside and it worked. So I found out that I have a problem with database and the problem was not having a correct user associated with DB. Correcting that solved the issue. Don't know why I got minus points for asking this!